# meteor- npm version error

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

ERROR

> While reading package from `/home/meteor/rschtml5_2018-05-07_18:41/ageroRSCHTML/packages/npm-container`:
>      package.js:15:7: must declare exact version of dependency: dependencies@[object Object]

**strong text**

```
var path = Npm.require('path');
var fs = Npm.require('fs');

Package.describe({
  summary: 'Contains all your npm dependencies',
     version: '1.0.0',
//  version: '3.10.10',
  name: 'npm-container'
});

var packagesJsonFile = path.resolve('./packages.json');
try {
  var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(packagesJsonFile);
  var packages = JSON.parse(fileContent.toString());
  Npm.depends(packages);
} catch (ex) {
  console.error('ERROR: packages.json parsing error [ ' + ex.message + ' ]');
}

// Adding the app's packages.json as a used file for this package will get
// Meteor to watch it and reload this package when it changes
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.add_files(['index.js', '../../packages.json'], 'server');
});
```

Comment: Meteor packages work with exact npm dependency version, save the time to try to read in the json file and write the npm depends code manually.

Comment: var path = Npm.require('path');
var fs = Npm.require('fs');

Package.describe({
  summary: 'Contains all your npm dependencies',
  version: '1.0.0',
  name: 'npm-container'
});

var packagesJsonFile = path.resolve('./packages.json');
try {
  var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(packagesJsonFile);
  var packages = JSON.parse(fileContent.toString());
  Npm.depends(packages);
} catch (ex) {
  console.error('ERROR: packages.json parsing error [ ' + ex.message + ' ]');
}

Comment: // Adding the app's packages.json as a used file for this package will get
// Meteor to watch it and reload this package when it changes
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.add_files(['index.js', '../../packages.json'], 'server');

Comment: following is package.json{
  "dependencies": {
    "RSCApiWrapper": "file:../xxxxxx",
    "Utilities": "file:../RSCModules/Utilities",
    "archiver": "^1.3.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.28.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "base-64": "0.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "forever": "^0.15.3",
    "forever-monitor": "^1.7.1",
    "frep": "^0.2.3",
    "isbinaryfile": "3.0.0",
    "later": "1.2.0",
    "mustache": "^2.3.0",
    "urlencode": "^1.1.0"
  }
}

Comment: Can you edit these details into your question please? They are unreadable in comments